# Wifi stops working 2 mins after startup; must manually disconnect and reconnect to work every time (Windows 10)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, connection

I am using Windows 10, and my Wifi has never given me any problems until a forced update about 3 weeks ago.

Ever since then, when the computer boots up, the internet would work for about 2 minutes, then it will fail to work while the wifi is still connected. Then I have to disconnect it manually, and connect it again, which causes it to never disconnect or have problems for the rest of the day until I turn off and boot up the computer again.

I tried network troubleshooting, but it only resolves the problem for a while, before the wifi fails and I have to reconnect again manually. I also tried many solutions, like making sure power plan doesn't turn off the wifi adaptor automatically, change internet protocol settings, turn off proxy settings etc., but nothing works.

I hate to do this every time when the computer starts up. Is there a permanent solution to this?